# Seeeduino XIAO read PWM duration (period) using timers change Pins freom D2 to D1

Tags: seeeduino-xiao

I designed a circuitboard and need to proof the function.Therefore i have to modify the code to read from Pins D1 instead of D2.
Unfourtunatly i am not that familar with the high level programming so im not sure if i got all changes.
Basically all PINS on the circuit are used.

Basecode foud here:
[Seeeduino XIAO write and read PWM duration (period) using timers](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85741/seeeduino-xiao-write-and-read-pwm-duration-period-using-timers)

Reading short square waves with Seeeduino XIAO pin D2

```
// Setup TC4 to capture pulse-width and period on digital pin D2 on Seeeduino Xiao
volatile boolean periodComplete;
volatile uint32_t isrPeriod;
volatile uint32_t isrPulsewidth;
uint32_t period;
uint32_t pulsewidth;

void setup()   {                
  SerialUSB.begin(115200);                         // Initialise the native serial port
  while(!SerialUSB);                               // Wait for the console to open
  
  PM->APBCMASK.reg |= PM_APBCMASK_EVSYS;           // Switch on the event system peripheral

  GCLK->GENDIV.reg = GCLK_GENDIV_DIV(1) |          // Divide the 48MHz system clock by 1 = 48MHz
                     GCLK_GENDIV_ID(4);            // Set division on Generic Clock Generator (GCLK) 4

  GCLK->GENCTRL.reg = GCLK_GENCTRL_IDC |           // Set the duty cycle to 50/50 HIGH/LOW
                      GCLK_GENCTRL_GENEN |         // Enable GCLK 4
                      GCLK_GENCTRL_SRC_DFLL48M |   // Set the clock source to 48MHz
                      GCLK_GENCTRL_ID(4);          // Set clock source on GCLK 4
  while (GCLK->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);               // Wait for synchronization
  
  GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg = GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN |         // Route GCLK4 to TC4 and TC5
                      GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK4 |     
                      GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TC4_TC5;     
  
  // Enable the port multiplexer on port pin PA10
  PORT->Group[PORTA].PINCFG[10].bit.PMUXEN = 1;
  // Set-up the pin as an EIC (interrupt) on port pin PA10
  PORT->Group[PORTA].PMUX[10 >> 1].reg |= PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_A;

  EIC->EVCTRL.reg |= EIC_EVCTRL_EXTINTEO10;                                // Enable event output on external interrupt 10
  EIC->CONFIG[1].reg |= EIC_CONFIG_SENSE2_HIGH;                            // Set event detecting a HIGH level
  EIC->INTENCLR.reg = EIC_INTENCLR_EXTINT10;                               // Disable interrupts on external interrupt 10
  EIC->CTRL.reg |= EIC_CTRL_ENABLE;                                        // Enable EIC peripheral
  while (EIC->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);                                        // Wait for synchronization
  
  EVSYS->USER.reg = EVSYS_USER_CHANNEL(1) |                                // Attach the event user (receiver) to channel 0 (n + 1)
                    EVSYS_USER_USER(EVSYS_ID_USER_TC4_EVU);                // Set the event user (receiver) as timer TC4

  EVSYS->CHANNEL.reg = EVSYS_CHANNEL_EDGSEL_NO_EVT_OUTPUT |                // No event edge detection
                       EVSYS_CHANNEL_PATH_ASYNCHRONOUS |                   // Set event path as asynchronous
                       EVSYS_CHANNEL_EVGEN(EVSYS_ID_GEN_EIC_EXTINT_10) |   // Set event generator (sender) as external interrupt 10
                       EVSYS_CHANNEL_CHANNEL(0);                           // Attach the generator (sender) to channel 0

  TC4->COUNT32.EVCTRL.reg = TC_EVCTRL_TCEI |               // Enable the TC event input
                            //TC_EVCTRL_TCINV |              // Invert the event input
                            TC_EVCTRL_EVACT_PPW;           // Set up the timer for capture: CC0 period, CC1 pulsewidth
                  
  TC4->COUNT32.CTRLC.reg = TC_CTRLC_CPTEN1 |               // Enable capture on CC1
                           TC_CTRLC_CPTEN0;                // Enable capture on CC0
  while (TC4->COUNT32.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);                // Wait for synchronization

  NVIC_SetPriority(TC4_IRQn, 0);      // Set the Nested Vector Interrupt Controller (NVIC) priority for TC4 to 0 (highest)
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TC4_IRQn);           // Connect the TC4 timer to the Nested Vector Interrupt Controller (NVIC)
 
  TC4->COUNT32.INTENSET.reg = TC_INTENSET_MC1 |            // Enable compare channel 1 (CC1) interrupts
                              TC_INTENSET_MC0;             // Enable compare channel 0 (CC0) interrupts
  
  TC4->COUNT32.CTRLA.reg = //TC_CTRLA_PRESCSYNC_PRESC |      // Overflow on precaler clock, (rather than the GCLK)
                           TC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_DIV1  |      // Set prescaler to 1, 48MHz/1 = 48MHz
                           TC_CTRLA_MODE_COUNT32;          // Set TC4/TC5 to 32-bit timer mode
                          
  TC4->COUNT32.CTRLA.bit.ENABLE = 1;                       // Enable TC4
  while (TC4->COUNT32.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);                // Wait for synchronization
}

void loop() { 
  if (periodComplete)                             // Check if the period is complete
  {
    noInterrupts();                               // Read the new period and pulse-width
    period = isrPeriod;                  
    pulsewidth = isrPulsewidth;
    interrupts();
    SerialUSB.print("PW: ");
    SerialUSB.print(pulsewidth);
    SerialUSB.print(F("   "));
    SerialUSB.print("P: ");
    SerialUSB.println(period);
    periodComplete = false;                       // Start a new period
  }
}

void TC4_Handler()                                // Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) for timer TC4
{    
  // Check for match counter 0 (MC0) interrupt
  if (TC4->COUNT32.INTFLAG.bit.MC0)            
  {
    TC4->COUNT32.READREQ.reg = TC_READREQ_RREQ |           // Enable a read request
                               TC_READREQ_ADDR(0x18);      // Offset address of the CC0 register
    while (TC4->COUNT32.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);              // Wait for (read) synchronization
    isrPeriod = TC4->COUNT32.CC[0].reg;                    // Copy the period  
    periodComplete = true;                                 // Indicate that the period is complete
  }

  // Check for match counter 1 (MC1) interrupt
  if (TC4->COUNT32.INTFLAG.bit.MC1)          
  {
    TC4->COUNT32.READREQ.reg = TC_READREQ_RREQ |           // Enable a read request
                               TC_READREQ_ADDR(0x1A);      // Offset address of the CC1 register
    while (TC4->COUNT32.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);              // Wait for (read) synchronization
    isrPulsewidth = TC4->COUNT32.CC[1].reg;                // Copy the pulse-width
  }
}
```

Do i only have to change the IOs:
from:
PORT->Group[PORTA].PINCFG[10].bit.PMUXEN = 1;
PORT->Group[PORTA].PMUX[10 >> 1].reg |= PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_A;
to:
PORT->Group[PORTA].PINCFG[4].bit.PMUXEN = 1;
PORT->Group[PORTA].PMUX[4 >> 1].reg |= PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_A;

or do i need to mod more code?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the changes you mentioned, your `EIC_EVCTRL_EXTINTEO10`, `EIC_INTENCLR_EXTINT10`, and `EVSYS_ID_GEN_EIC_EXTINT_10` usages will need to be changed to `EIC_EVCTRL_EXTINTE4`, `EIC_INTENCLR_EXTINT4` and to `EVSYS_ID_GEN_EIC_EXTINT_4`, to re-target the event system source, because `PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_A` on both [these pins](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/v1.8.3/variants/XIAO_m0/variant.cpp#L28-L29) routes the signal to the EIC, but not to the exact same interrupt number.  The `EIC->CONFIG` line needs to change to the first group of 8 (`[0]`) and fourth SENSE within that group (`EIC_CONFIG_SENSE4_HIGH`) to the change to D1 (PA04) uses EXTINT4.  This is something I'd left out of the first edit before I'd been able to test. I did eventually find a XIAO to test with and these modifications seem to make it work just fine on digital pin 1 now instead of digital pin 2.

```cpp
EIC->EVCTRL.reg    |= EIC_EVCTRL_EXTINTE4;
EIC->CONFIG[0].reg |= EIC_CONFIG_SENSE4_HIGH;
EIC->INTENCLR.reg   = EIC_INTENCLR_EXTINT4;
EIC->CTRL.reg      |= EIC_CTRL_ENABLE;
while (EIC->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);
```

...

```cpp
EVSYS->CHANNEL.reg = EVSYS_CHANNEL_EDGSEL_NO_EVT_OUTPUT |                
                     EVSYS_CHANNEL_PATH_ASYNCHRONOUS |
                     EVSYS_CHANNEL_EVGEN(EVSYS_ID_GEN_EIC_EXTINT_4) |
                     EVSYS_CHANNEL_CHANNEL(0);
```

---

The changes you'd mentioned and those I've said above as diff:

```
--- original.ino
+++ modified.ino
@@ -24,14 +24,14 @@
                       GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK4 |     
                       GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID_TC4_TC5;     
   
-  // Enable the port multiplexer on port pin PA10
-  PORT->Group[PORTA].PINCFG[10].bit.PMUXEN = 1;
-  // Set-up the pin as an EIC (interrupt) on port pin PA10
-  PORT->Group[PORTA].PMUX[10 >> 1].reg |= PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_A;
+  // Enable the port multiplexer on port pin PA04
+  PORT->Group[PORTA].PINCFG[4].bit.PMUXEN = 1;
+  // Set-up the pin as an EIC (interrupt) on port pin PA04
+  PORT->Group[PORTA].PMUX[4 >> 1].reg |= PORT_PMUX_PMUXE_A;
 
-  EIC->EVCTRL.reg |= EIC_EVCTRL_EXTINTEO10;                                // Enable event output on external interrupt 10
-  EIC->CONFIG[1].reg |= EIC_CONFIG_SENSE2_HIGH;                            // Set event detecting a HIGH level
-  EIC->INTENCLR.reg = EIC_INTENCLR_EXTINT10;                               // Disable interrupts on external interrupt 10
+  EIC->EVCTRL.reg |= EIC_EVCTRL_EXTINTEO4;                                 // Enable event output on external interrupt 4
+  EIC->CONFIG[0].reg |= EIC_CONFIG_SENSE4_HIGH;                            // Set event detecting a HIGH level
+  EIC->INTENCLR.reg = EIC_INTENCLR_EXTINT4;                                // Disable interrupts on external interrupt 4
   EIC->CTRL.reg |= EIC_CTRL_ENABLE;                                        // Enable EIC peripheral
   while (EIC->STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);                                        // Wait for synchronization
   
@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@
 
   EVSYS->CHANNEL.reg = EVSYS_CHANNEL_EDGSEL_NO_EVT_OUTPUT |                // No event edge detection
                        EVSYS_CHANNEL_PATH_ASYNCHRONOUS |                   // Set event path as asynchronous
-                       EVSYS_CHANNEL_EVGEN(EVSYS_ID_GEN_EIC_EXTINT_10) |   // Set event generator (sender) as external interrupt 10
+                       EVSYS_CHANNEL_EVGEN(EVSYS_ID_GEN_EIC_EXTINT_4) |    // Set event generator (sender) as external interrupt 4
                        EVSYS_CHANNEL_CHANNEL(0);                           // Attach the generator (sender) to channel 0
 
   TC4->COUNT32.EVCTRL.reg = TC_EVCTRL_TCEI |               // Enable the TC event input
```